# python sorted function with user defined cmp functions

Tags: python, sorting

I want to order the items in a dictionary using various comparator functions.
Please see my example code below. It is the last part using cmpRatio function with sorted() that does not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any idea!

```
mydict = { 'a1': (1,6),
          'a2': (10,2),
          'a3': (5,3),
          'a4': (1,2),
          'a5': (3,9),
          'a6': (9,7) }

# sort by first element of the value tuple: WORKS
print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): v[0])

# sort by second element of the value tuple: WORKS
print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): v[1])

# THIS is what I can't get working:
def cmpRatio(x,y):
   sx = float(x[0])/x[1]
   sy = float(y[0])/y[1]
   return sx < sy

# sort by sum of the elements in the value tuple: DOES NOT WORK
print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): v, cmp=cmpRatio)
```

Comment: please try to format your code using the little `{ }` box on the editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid `cmp` functions where possible because they are slow. They have to be re-evaluated for each comparison. Using a `key` makes it so the key only needs to be computed once.

```
print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): float(v[0])/v[1])
```

Also, you say you want to sort by the sum of the value items, yet you are sorting by the difference. Sum would look like:

```
print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): sum(v))
```

As mentioned in other answers, for the purpose of really wanting to define a `cmp` function, you are not returning the proper value (must be -1,0, or 1).

```
return cmp(sx,sy)
```

But also if you are just using a lambda to get the value, you can replace that with `itemgetter` which should be faster than a python-side function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), cmp=cmpRatio)
```

If you are trying to store up sort operations, it would be much better to store the key functions:

```
key_ops = {
    'sum': lambda (k,v): sum(v),
    'ratio': lambda (k,v): float(v[0])/v[1]),
}

def print_op(aDict, opName):
    print sorted(aDict.iteritems(), key=key_ops[opName])

... # some place later in code
print_op(mydict, 'sum')
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, sum and ratio where two of the various comparator functions I want to use. Your solution works perfectly fine, but my example is not only slow, it simply does not work, and I still want to understand what I am doing wrong.  I want to be able to define the comparator functions and use them as parameters to some other optimization function, that is the underlying reason I am trying to use cmp. Thanks!

Comment: @RuxandraPalmtag: I still don't know why you would want a `cmp` function. You should be defining multiple `lambda` operations for the key instead. But I updated regarding your `cmp` function.

Comment: Oh, I get it now: the return value, I read about it but didn't register :) Thank you for the efficiency comment, I'll try using the key with lambda and see how it works with my code!

Answer (score 4):

you comparison function should return a (negative / zero / positive) value when the first argument is (less than / equal to / greater than) the second value (unlike a comparator given to `std::sort(...)` in C++).

i.e. instead of

```
return sx < sy
```

do

```
return cmp(sx,sy)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort by the sum of the value tuple (according to your comment), you could use :

```
print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda v: sum(v[1]))
```

If you want to sort by the ratio (according to your code):

```
print sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda v: float(v[1][0])/v[1][1])
```